# Famo.us - Anchor tag as content of Surface

Tags: anchor, famo.us

Is it possible to use anchor tag as content of Famo.us Surface?

```
   function _createTitle() {
    var titleSurface = new Surface({
        size: [true, true],
        content: this.options.title,  //<a href="#">Click me !</a>
        properties: {
            color: 'white',
            fontFamily: 'AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBold',
            fontSize: this.options.fontSize + 'px',
            textTransform: 'uppercase',
            pointerEvents : 'none',
            zIndex:10,
            marginTop:'15px'
        }
    });
```

I get anchor tag displayed in DOM tree, but i cant click on it, neither my cursor change on hover.

Comment: Downvote, when someone try's to find solution...not everybody here is expirienced programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by removing  pointerEvents : 'none' porperty. Pretty self explanatory :P I just didn't see that property in my head.